# Ubuntu 17.04: Can't get Google Chrome to sign in to sync data

Tags: google-chrome, 17.04, chromium, sync

Fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04 yesterday.

Installed Chrome. Signed in to Google account. Sync won't sync. After a while I get the following error.

> Failed to start up the sync backend.
>   Please make sure your network connection is working and if the problem persists, please sign out and sign in again to refresh your credentials.

So I sign out. Close Chrome. Open Chrome. Now I get the following error.

> Profile error occurred
>   Something went wrong when opening your profile. Some features may be unavailable.

I dismiss the pop up error and attempt to sign in again. Sometimes I can and other times I just get a blank screen where normally it would allow me to enter my email and password.

So I try:

- Removing Chrome via terminal and doing a purge afterwards.
- Manually removing the `~/.config/Google-Chrome` folder.
- Reinstall Chrome from a newly downloaded .deb installer.

And now I'm back to having issues with sync again. Done this two or three times and I still have issues.

I've logged out of Chrome on my Windows 10 laptop and log back in with no issues. So it isn't my network (obviously) and it isn't my account. I've used Chrome and it's syncing features on Ubuntu MATE with no issues.

I'm lost, any other spots config files or other files from Google Chrome may be hiding that I can delete?

I've also tired this with Chromium and Chrome Beta and I have the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it myself, was as simple as rebooting the computer. :D

Comment: Not sure why the question is off-topic as this answer fixed my problem.

Comment: Fixed mine too, on 17.10. Using Chromium 65.0.3325.181.